# typeahead.js get input value on button click

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I hope I can explain what I'm trying to do...

I am using twitter typeahead.js to show a list of vegetables. The user starts typing the name of a vegetable and then can select a vegetable from the list which, when selected, populates the input. The user then clicks a button "add item". When this button is clicked, I want to add the value of the input to a div (building up a list of items).

I am having problems as the $('.typeahead').typeahead('val') method doesn't seem to be working at all (error: undefined). trying $('.typeahead').val() returns an empty string.

How can I get the input value when a button is pressed?

```
//the url produce/get_produce_items returns an array of vegetables. The filter organises these into value (the vegetable name) and id (the id of the vegetable in the db)
var produce_items = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                prefetch: {
                    url: site_url('produce/get_produce_items'),
                    filter: function(list) {
                        return $.map(list, function(produce_item) { return { value: produce_item.name,id: produce_item.id }; });
                    },
                    ttl:10000
                }
            });

            produce_items.initialize();

            var typeaheadSettings = {
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 1,
            };
            var typeAheadDataset = {
                name: 'produce_items',
                displayKey: 'value',
                valueKey: 'value',
                source: produce_items.ttAdapter(),
            };

            $('#items_list .typeahead').typeahead(typeaheadSettings,typeAheadDataset);

//here's the button that is clicked, and when clicked should replace the typeahead with a div containing the typeahead value            
$('#add_donation_item_line_btn').click(function() {
                var item_count = $('input[name=item_count]');
                var count = item_count.val();
                var nextCount = parseInt(count) + 1;

                //firm the line (swap the input out for a div)
var val = $('#items_list > div#don_line_'+count+' .typeahead').val();
                firmLine(count,val);

                $('#items_list .typeahead').trigger('added');

                item_count.val(nextCount);

            });

            $('#items_list .typeahead').on('added',function(val){
                $('#items_list .typeahead').typeahead(typeaheadSettings,typeAheadDataset);
            });
            $('#items_list .typeahead').on('typeahead:selected',function(evt, item){
$(this).parent('span').parent('div').find('input[type=hidden]').val(item.id);
            });

            function firmLine(count,val) {
                var line = $('#items_list > div#don_line_'+count+' .typeahead');
                line.typeahead('destroy');
                line.replaceWith('<div class="span2 typeahead-replacement">'+val+'</div>');   
            }
```

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
$('#add_donation_item_line_btn').click(function() {
  // Get value of input
  var foo = $('input.typeahead.tt-input').val();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Dan,

Perhaps you can make use of the `typeahead:selected` event and temporarily store the selected datum.

```
var selectedDatum;

$('.typeahead').on('typeahead:selected', function(event, datum) {
  selectedDatum = datum;
});
```

Then, when it comes time to use the datum (in the div-input swap), you can just call upon the existing store (`selectedDatum`). You may need to add some logic around clearing this store when the input value is updated, but that should be fairly easy (using some combination of `typeahead:opened`, `keyup`, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @tbloncar. Also good discussion on the topic here: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/193

Answer (score 0):

From what I have observerd 
when we focus out of the inputBox on which typeahead is applied then $('.typeahead').typeahead('val')  works.

But if case the focus is still in the input box , lets say one is doing something onchange or oninput , then to get the value in the input box we'll need 
$('.typeahead').val();